# How can I change the Sprite Renderer for only the gameObject I tap?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Brand new to Unity, working on a basic prototype of a game concept.
I'm trying to add a 3x3 grid of circles which toggle color when tapped on a mobile device.
Using Raycasting and Collision boxes, I've been able to successfully detect input and toggle the color, but when I do, it toggles the color for every circle, rather than just the one I tap.

Using `Debug.Log(hit.collider.name)` I can see that the program knows which circle I tapped, so I think I've set up Raycasting correctly.

Can anyone help with this?

Here is the script:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class colorChange : MonoBehaviour
    {
        SpriteRenderer sprite;
        bool isPressed;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            isPressed = false;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {

                    Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
                    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(worldPoint, Vector2.zero);

                    if (hit.collider != null)
                    {   

                        if (isPressed == false)
                        {
                            Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
                            sprite.color = new Color(0, 1, 0, 1);
                            isPressed = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
                            sprite.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
                            isPressed = false;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about instead of:

```
sprite.color = new Color(1,1,1,1);
```

Do:

```
hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1,1,1,1)
```

Since you do know the hit object is right.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I just had to change `hit.gameObject` to `hit.collider.gameObject` and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Ah sorry for that, glad I could help!